# Possible to set image style based on aspect ratio instead of px dimensions?

Tags: 8, media

I'd like to create an image style that uses an aspect ratio, so that images maintain their general dimensions but get cropped based on that ratio. Essentially this would mean that a 16:9 image style would crop a 1600x1200 img to 1600x900, and a 2000x900 img to 1600x900.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a use-case for image styles, I'd just do this in CSS, with `background-size: cover;` or `object-fit: cover` depending on the use-case

Comment: Thanks @Hudri. I'd come across the `object-fit` option but wanted to see if I may have been missing something obvious on the Drupal side of things. Wonder how hard this would be to implement in contrib